# Convert JSON string to strongly typed class object in C#

Tags: javascript, json, nsjsonserialization, generic-collections, json-deserialization

I am trying to convert Json string to Strongly typed object.

Json String:

```
{   "ResultSet": { "Description": "ADS Loading Complet - Service request failed",
"failedReason": "ORA-06550: line 1, column 36:\nPLS-00302: component 'SP_GET_LOADING_END_DATE1' must     be declared\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored",
"isSuccess": false,
"statusCode": 400
}
```

Class :

```
public class ResultSet
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string failedReason { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.Net.HttpStatusCode statusCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this but no luck.

```
 ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet();
 resultSet = json_serializer.Deserialize<ResultSet>(jsonString);
```

Please suggest better ways of doing it..

Comment: I don't know which serializer you use but I recommend you to use Netwonsoft.Json library from NUGET. What is your exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of `ResultSet` is an extra member in JSON you have to capsulate the ResultSet in an extra Class

```
public class ResultSetJson
{
    public ResultSet ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
ResultSet resultSet = json_serializer.Deserialize<ResultSetJson>(jsonString).ResultSet;
```

or

```
ResultSetJson resultSetJson = json_serializer.Deserialize<ResultSetJson>(jsonString);
ResultSet resultSet = resultSetJson.ResultSet;
```

Comment: This works for me thanks.. Ihave used JavaScriptSerializer
    ResultSet resultSet =  json_serializer.Deserialize<ResultSetJson>(jsonString).ResultSet;

Comment: Hai,How to avoid this one more wrapper class - ResultSetJson ?. Is there possibilities to avoid to have this member with in the class?

Comment: when you want to avoid this you have to change your JSON and don't capsule the content in an extra field